# Displaying data as flowchart in web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Im building an application in ASP.NET MVC that has a workflow component.

Im looking for something/ideas for displaying the underlying workflow data as a flowchart.

Im NOT looking for a flowcharting tool, but something that displays data as a flowchart.

Does anyone have some experience with this that could offer their wisdom?

Cheers,
Byron

Comment: I generally speak hate the workflow tools you are describing... but I have wanted to research good options.  Graphviz looks promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) useful.  You can generate a text description of a graph, and it will lay it out nicely for you.